# My JQuery Toggle not functioning properly

Tags: toggle, jquery

Why is my jQuery toggle function not working?

See this demo: http://project.4greality.com/category/budget-homes

My Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a.switchThumb").toggle(function(){
  $(this).addClass("swap"); 
    $("div.containerDiv").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $("#containerDiv").fadeIn("fast").addClass("displayToggleNone");

        });

    }, 

 function () {
  $(this).removeClass("swap");
    $("div.containerDiv2").fadeOut("fast", function() {
           $("#containerDiv2").fadeIn("fast").removeClass("displayToggleNone");

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: With your second function, why are you removing the class?

Comment: Also the JavaScript console (Chromium 17/Ubuntu 11.04) reports the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hoverIntent'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like below to toggle thumbnail and detailed view.

I am not sure why you try to fadeOut the div first and fadeIn the same again and then hide it.

Try below and let me know how it goes,

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("a.switchThumb").toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass("swap"); 
    $("#containerDiv").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $("#containerDiv2").fadeIn("fast");
    });
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("swap");
    $("#containerDiv2").fadeOut("fast", function() {
           $("#containerDiv").fadeIn("fast");    
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: can i get a explanation why not using add class? Just using fadeIn and Fadeout ?

Comment: @AnitaMandal fadeOut will eventually make the `#element { display: none; }`. It is more like you are adding additional class with same style to the element which is already `{ display: none; }`

Comment: Thanks a lot this answer will helps others.